# HDMI Audio only when display resolution change

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi, display-resolution

I have a weird issue with my 16.04 Ubuntu installation. When I boot it, it's impossible to get audio through HDMI. If I play some video or audio (youtube, VLC, Spotify) I can see the bar moving on pavucontrol and the sound settings.

So, to get this to work I need to follow this steps:

1. Play some video or music anywhere on the PC
2. Go to Display settings and change the resolution
3. At this point I got audio working, so I change the resolution back to the original (1920x1080)

If I stop the video or music for a while, the PC loose HDMI audio, so I have to make the steps again.

I have recent hardware:
Z270 chipset motherboard
i5-7600k Kaby Lake CPU
(No GPU)

I tried to set manually the audio device on pavucontrol, but it doesn't work.

Any hint on what can I do?

**UPDATE 1:**

I tried every device combination on pavucontrol, when I had no HDMI audio, with no luck. But when I enable HDMI audio (with the 3 steps above), I can change the device on pavucontrol and see that audio only work if I select HDMI3 as my default device.

**UPDATE 2:**

aplay -l log:

```
jose@desktop:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC1220 Analog [ALC1220 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC1220 Digital [ALC1220 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems some other audio device also available in your hardware, which is enumerated as default device.
Pls look at this link, This will help you to configure your HDMI display as default device.

```
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture#Set_the_default_sound_card
```

Even if the issue not resolved, **Post your `aplay -l` logs here**

[In pavucontrol, you need to select the default device like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtMGk.png)

Comment: Hi! I had selected the default audio device (HDMI3), and tried every option on that combobox, but still no audio. I will post my aplay log after work (the problem is on my personal desktop)

Comment: Updated original post with more data

Comment: post your  aplay -l output logs

Comment: aplay -l Log posted

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem. I solved it cheching "*aplay -l*" log and find out my list of cards and devices.

Afterwards I used this command to check which set of card/devices was the right one

```
$ aplay -D plughw:0,3 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
```

After **plughw:** you have to put card,device found in your "palay-l" log.
your hdmi card is obviuously the 0 and for the device you have to try this command for devices (until you hear a sound through hdmi device): 3 / 7 / 8 / 9 / 10

Once you found your set of card/device you have to edit /etc/pulse/default.pa ,
find the line

```
#load-module module-alsa-sink
```

uncomment it and change it like this:

```
load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,0
```

where 0,0 is your card/device set found before.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I didn't solve my problem with onboard sound. But, after buying a GPU, and install the driver, the sound started to work through HDMI.

Comment: What GPU have you bought?

Comment: One GTX 1060 6GB from EVGA